# Counting the number of shapes in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to count the number of shapes in an image of a board game. For some reason, the count is completely off.

I have been using code from the web (for example, https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/)

I only need opencv for this, has anyone else had this problem, and how do I limit this to only the squares that I am interested in?

[This is the same image as below but the background is now black. Now there are more center-dots than necessary all around the edge of the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjfJN.png)

[I want the center dot to appear in every square on the board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PMKR.png)

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your code an input images.

Comment: can you post the original image without all of the processing stuff?

Answer (score 6):

I used paint to remove the edges of the numbers that were interrupting the white lines of each box. I assume that those numbers and dots were things that you added and not part of the original image.

Here is the image after my modifications

[image]

I made a mask by looking for white in the image. I dilated the results to get clearer separation and inverted so that each box was white.

[image]

I used findContours to get the contour of each white object in the mask. I filtered the contours by size to get rid of the arrows, letter bits, and the background of the image. From there I drew the centroid of each remaining contour.

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("chutes_n_ladders.png");

# mask
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 240, 255);

# dilate and invert
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8);
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 1);
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask);

# contours
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# remove very large and very small contours
filtered = [];
low = 1000;
high = 100000;
for con in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(con);
    if low < area and area < high:
        filtered.append(con);

# draw centers of each
print("Shapes: " + str(len(filtered)));
for con in filtered:
    M = cv2.moments(con);
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00']);
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00']);
    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (0, 200, 100), -1);

# show
cv2.imshow("Image", img);
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```